# JDK instead of or in addition to JRE?

Tags: java, runtime, development-environment

I have a question about the two versions of Java: JRE (Java Runtime Environment) and JDK (Java Development Kit).

Is the JDK installed and used in addition to the JRE or is it used instead of the JRE so that one could install the JDK as a JRE with simply more functions for developers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must understand that JDK includes JRE. JRE is Java Virtual Machine where your Java programs run on whereas JDK is full featured Software Development Kit for Java

From the docs:

> **JRE  (Java Runtime environment):**
>
> - It is an implementation of the Java Virtual Machine* which actually executes Java programs.
> - Java Runtime Environment is a plug-in needed for running java programs.
> - The JRE is smaller than the JDK so it needs less Disk space.
> - The JRE can be downloaded/supported freely from https://www.java.com
> - It includes the JVM , Core libraries and other additional components to run applications and applets written in Java.
>
> **JDK (Java Development Kit)**
>
> - It is a bundle of software that you can use to develop Java based applications.
> - Java Development Kit is needed for developing java applications.
> - The JDK needs more Disk space as it contains the JRE along with various development tools.
> - The JDK can be downloaded/supported freely from https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/
> - It includes the JRE, set of API classes, Java compiler, Webstart and additional files needed to write Java applets and applications.

Answer (score 1):

They're not two versions of Java. JRE is the Java Virtual Machine which executes bytecode. On the other hand, JDK is the Java Development Kit, which allows you to write Java code, compile it into bytecode and ships a JRE to execute it.

If your client just needs to execute Java, it needs to install the JRE only. If you want to run Java applications and create them install JDK.

Answer (score 1):

One can install JDK..which has JRE also.